# How can I use regex for “contains this word”

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm trying to setup tracking in Google Analytics.

The goal URL is:

```
www.example.com/2006/blog-post_4.html 
www.example.com/2006/blog-post_4.html?m=0 
www.example.com/2006/blog-post_4.html?m=1
```

ignore

```
www.example.com/2006/blog-post_40.html 
www.example.com/2006/blog-post_4.html#hashtag
www.example.com/2006/blog-post_4.html?m=0#hashtag
www.example.com/2006/blog-post_4.html?m=1#hashtag
```

my attempt

```
.*blog-post_4(.html|.html.m=.)?(?!..)
```

http://goo.gl/9LjV9P

Comment: For starters, you probably have to escape the dots, e.g. `\.html`.

Comment: GA regex is RE2 flavor. It does not support lookarounds. Try `blog-post_4[.]html([?]m=[0-9]+)?$`.

Comment: Thank you very much.
Still, if you can, advise tool for such tasks

Sorry for angliyskiy

Comment: A che tam s angliyskim? :) Mezhdu prochim, kak Vam moe predlozhenie? Opublikovat' otvet?

Comment: Я.Метрика одобряет, всё работает (в отчётах хэштеги не учитываются )
Большое вам спасибо

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew напишите любой отдельный комментарий, для того чтобы я смог отметить ваш ответ как решением. И если вас не затруднит, посоветуйте пожалуйста пару инструментов для облегчения написание url:регулярных выражений (интересует только статистика )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
blog-post_4[.]html([?]m=[0-9]+)?$
```

This regex will match `blog-post_4` literslly, then a literal dot will get matched with `[.]` followed with a literal character sequence `html` followed with an optional group (since it is enclosed with parentheses followed immediately with a `?` quantifier) that matches a question mark, `m=`+ one or more digits, and then followed with an end of string marker.

Your expression does not work because you use a negative lookahead that is not supported by the RE2regex library that Google Analytics is using.

**Note**: to test your expressions in GA you can use Google utilities when you create the view. Please read [these instructions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2936903?hl=en).

Comment: Тестировать можно и на других сайтах, просто надо учитывать то, что нельзя использовать конструкции типа блоков предварительного просмотра.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics automatically disregards fragments, so you won't need to worry about filtering them out.

So your destination goal configuration can be something like this, which ignores those strings that you've indicated (which in the end is really just the one with `blog-post_40.html`:

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, come again?